# Status of SpaceX's Private Trip Around the Moon Mission

Tags: spacex

In a [February 2017 press release](http://www.spacex.com/news/2017/02/27/spacex-send-privately-crewed-dragon-spacecraft-beyond-moon-next-year) titled "SpaceX to Send Privately Crewed Dragon Spacecraft Beyond the Moon Next Year" SpaceX announced

> We are excited to announce that SpaceX has been approached to fly two
>   private citizens on a trip around the Moon late next year. They have
>   already paid a significant deposit to do a Moon mission.

It's 25% of the way through "next year" now.  What's the status of this amazing mission?

Answer (score 3):

It seems very likely that it has been cancelled, although it has not been explicitly declared as such. We do know that Falcon Heavy will not be man rated. As the mission was supposed to be launched on Falcon Heavy, it seems rather unlikely that the mission will proceed as planned.

I rather suspect they will be given an opportunity to fly on a BFR mission, when available.

Comment: I feel like it's pretty confirmed they are pushing it back to BFR for the time being, with the option to reconsider based on BFR progress. http://spacenews.com/spacex-no-longer-planning-crewed-missions-on-falcon-heavy/

Comment: @Saiboogu consider posting your own answer, that link is the best reference I have seen about this.